# Dejar el scroll en la misma posicion al cambiar de pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

quiero que al cambiar de página el scroll se quede en la misma posición de la pagina anterior.
Es decir si estaba en el footer, que al cambiar de pagina siga ahi
El comportamiento actual cuando se cambia de página es que el scroll regrese al inicio.
Quisiera hacer eso con jquery o javascript

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo enseñar tu código para que nos sea mas fácil poder ayudarte. Por otro lado ¿Por que ibas a querer hacer ese comportamiento?

Comment: Es un requerimiento que me piden. No puedo subir el codigo por temas de la empresa.

Comment: Imagino que teneis un boton en el footer a modo de flecha hacia arriba que te manda arriba del todo, tipico en muchas paginas. Antes de  cambiar de pagina tienes que guardarte la posicion del eje de las y en una varible global y luego al cargar cualquier pagina hacer scroll a esa posicion. y si no la encuentra pues arriba del todo.

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822